# lifecycle delphi datasnap qual usar?

Tags: delphi

Saudações a todos.

Desenvolvi um app para android usando a tecnologia datasnap reflection REST com JSON delphi usando no server mecanismo de conecxao de dados firedac.
Esse app tem basicamente a função de consulta de dados.

A minha dúvida é qual tipo de lifecycle seria o ideal a ser usado.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A propriedade [`LifeCycle`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE7/en/Datasnap.DSServer.TDSServerClass.LifeCycle) tem basicamente três opções:

- *Server*: O servidor mantém uma única instância da classe no server, todos os clientes ao solicitar essa classe receberão sempre a mesma instância (*Singleton*).
- *Session*:  O servidor mantém uma instância da classe por sessão do DataSnap, cada cliente recebe uma instância diferente da classe.
- *Invocation*: A cada invocação de um cliente uma instância da classe será criada e logo depois destruída (*Stateless*).

A documentação cita que para clientes **REST**, se o ciclo de vida escolhido for *Session* em [*DSServerClass*](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE7/en/Datasnap.DSServer.TDSServerClass), *Session* se comportará como sendo *Invocation*. Se não tiver maiores problemas, a primeira opção, *Server*, pode ser apropriada.

Comment: Estou usando Session e ele está se comportando como Session, tanto é que depois de um tempo de inatividade ele perde a sessão e tenho que reconectar. Na verdade eu queria saber que prejuízo eu tenho em usar invocation no meu caso.

Comment: @edmjunio Basicamente ao usar *invocation* você cria uma nova instância para cada invocação do cliente.

Comment: Ok isso eu tenho ciência mas teria algum ônus essa modalidade?  Pelo que eu andei lendo a tecnologia REST é por padrão statless ou seja invocation. Eu uso autenticação no processo de acesso será que usando invocation terei que refazer a autenticação a cada solicitação ao server ?

Comment: @edmjunio Acredito que em teoria sim.

Comment: Vou testar e reporto

Answer (score 0):

Modifiquei o `lifecycle` no server para *invocation*. No cliente, modifiquei a propriedade `PreserveSessionID` do componente *DRestConection* para *false* pois não tenho a necessidade de gerenciar ou criar sessões. Desta forma caso ocorra indisponibilidade do *server* ou do *link* de internet assim que a interrupção for sanada o app conseguirá refazer a conexão.

A rotina de segurança que eu uso, é aplicada em dois momentos, no momento da criação do *mainform* onde os menus são montados e durante a conexão do componente *DRestConection* onde são passadas o login e senha para acesso aos métodos do servidor.

A principio funcionou estou fazendo mais testes para chegar a uma conclusão final.
Obrigado a todos pela ajuda.

Comment: Se isso funcionou para você, marque a sua resposta como aceita. Veja mais detalhes [aqui](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/1078/como-e-por-que-aceitar-uma-resposta/1079#1079).

Answer (score 0):

Se vc estiver utilizando REST e sem sessão o q é session naturalmente fica invocation nao precisa nem mudar. Pela caracteristica do protocolo mesmo. Conecta processa e desconecta.